# Maximum call stack size exceeded in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm recently creating a UI system with JQuery for which I'm Including other HTML pages from JQuery `.load()`

The code something look like this:

## load.js

```
function loadScript (url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = callback;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
Object.prototype.loadHTML = function (dir) {
    $(this).load(dir);
}
(function () {
     var apps = ['some_application']; //This is where, I list my apps.
     for (var x=0;x < apps.length;x++) {
         loadScript('apps/' + apps[x] . '/init.js');
     }
})();
```

## some_application/init.js

```
(function () {
    var x = system.createApplication({'title':'Some Application'}) //This function works fine, I have tried and It returns a HTML DOM.
    x.loadHTML('apps/some_application/html/main.html'); // This file exists.
})();
```

I am getting error saying

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

In file `jquery-1.12.0.min.js:3`.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This means you have infinite recursion. Check the call stack in the debugger to see what function calls are getting into a loop.

Comment: JQuery is minify therefore I can't check it in debugger.

Comment: You should still see all the function names in the stack trace

Comment: Anyways, I have ignored It and using AngularJS `ng-include` which is easier then JQuery and working for me :)